# How to submit a new maven plugin

Tags: maven

Say I have developed a plugin which I don't believe has been developed before. Can I submit this plugin to the maven community or does such a facility exist ? Is there a process required for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean submit your artifact to [The Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse), here is the complete user guide:

### [Sonatype OSS Maven Repository Usage Guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide)

> **1. Introduction**
>
> Sonatype OSSRH (OSS Repository Hosting Service) uses Nexus to provide Maven repository hosting service for open source projects: https://oss.sonatype.org/. You can deploy snapshots, stage releases, and promote your releases so they will be synced to [The Central Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/). All you need to do is to sign up a Sonatype JIRA account, create a JIRA ticket and make some POM/settings configuration. This document will guide you step by step for the details.
>
> ... ...